# Google Play Console Dashboard - is there a way to reset KPIs to their default form?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I've faced a problem with Google Play Console's **Dashboard** where after choosing some custom KPIs for my app, I'm not able to go back to the default ones.

**Default KPIs** (the ones you get after pressing the "Keep default KPIs" button) are: `New users acquired`, `Revenue`, `Daily ratings` & `Crashes and ANRs`.

Problem is, once you remove them, you're not able to bring them back. It's **impossible** to pick the same KPIs from the "Choose your KPIs" dialog. E.g. there's a `New user acquisitions` KPI that you can pick, but it looks & works differently from the default `New users acquired`.

What's even worse is that even the "Original default KPI" button (that appears once you remove all your KPIs) doesn't do what it should (e.g. it puts `New user acquisitions` KPI instead of `New users acquired`).

Did anyone face the same problem? Can anyone help?

Comment: This problem has already occurred
I don't know what the error is, but I have some applications that work and others do not work
I think they are trying to solve the problem